# Navigation inside future method flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

I am trying to navigate to a screen from a future method. However I get an error saying undefined name context. I tried navigating from Widget build but the parameter is created within this method and I need it for navigating. I've been stuck on this for a very long time. Any help will be really appreciated.

```
Future<void> addBookingConversation(Booking booking) async {
    Conversation conversation = Conversation();
    await conversation.addConversationToFirestore(booking.posting.host); //additional method working fine
    String text = "Hi, my name is ${AppConstants.currentUser.firstName}";
    await conversation.addMessageToFirestore(text); //additional method working fine
    //this is where i should navigate to the conversation page and facing the error here
    Navigator.push(
      context, //error here context undefined
      MaterialPageRoute(builder:
          (context) => ConversationPage(conversation: conversation,),
      ),
    );
  }
```

```
class ConversationPage extends StatefulWidget {

  final Conversation conversation;

  static final String routeName = '/conversationPageRoute';

  ConversationPage({this.conversation, Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ConversationPageState createState() => _ConversationPageState();
}

class _ConversationPageState extends State<ConversationPage> {

  Conversation _conversation;
  // additional code of wiget build
  }
```

Comment: put your `addBookingConversation` function below `Widget build(BuildContext context)` wherein `context` is defined.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your `Navigator` inside :

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_){
        //  Your Navigation here
 });
```

---

Your Code:

```
Future<void> addBookingConversation(Booking booking) async {
 ...
 WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_){
    Navigator.push(                                        // add your navigation here
      context, //error here context undefined
      MaterialPageRoute(builder:
          (context) => ConversationPage(conversation: conversation,),
      ),
    );
   ...
}
```

Comment: WidgetsBinding take too much time to execute. Slow progress

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where your function resides, so this is some general advice:

If you cannot access a variable in your method you have two options: pass it in as a parameter from the caller. Or return the result to the caller so they can do the part where the variable is needed themselves.

What does that mean for your scenario: either you need the `context` as an additional parameter in your method, or you need to return `Future<Conversation>` from your method and handle the navigation where it's called.

Personally, I'd favor the second option, since your business logic of starting a conversation and your in-app navigation are two different concerns that should not be mixed in one method.

Comment: I managed to fix it by adding the additional parameter of context. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call the navigator method anywhere in the app.

```
class NavigationService {
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> globalKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  Future<dynamic> navigateTo(Route Route) {   
  return globalKey.currentState.push(Route);
  }
}
```

and in main.dart.

```
 navigatorKey: NavigationService().globalKey,
```

and then anywhere within the app.
Just use this

```
Future<void> addBookingConversation(Booking booking) async {
Conversation conversation = Conversation();
await conversation.addConversationToFirestore(booking.posting.host); 
//additional method working fine
String text = "Hi, my name is ${AppConstants.currentUser.firstName}";
await conversation.addMessageToFirestore(text); //additional method working 
fine
//this is where i should navigate to the conversation page and facing the 
error here
NavigationService().navigateTo(
MaterialPageRoute(builder:
      (context) => ConversationPage(conversation: conversation,),
  ),);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This method help you to navigate the route without FutureBuilder. see the code

```
onPressed: () async {
          // then await the future You want to complete and then use `.then()` 
          //method to implement the code that you want to implement when the future is completed
          await //call your future widget //
              .then((result) {
            print('future completed');
          // Navigate here 
            // For errors use onError to show or check the errors.
          }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
            print(error);
          });
        }
```